# Unity receive event from object c

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, unity-game-engine

I want to create a ios plugin for unity. The function is send textmessage using some sdk. Well, here is my object c:

```
-(TextMessage*) CsendText:(NSString *)number CmsgContent:(NSString *)msg{
    return [MessagingApi sendText:(NSString*) number msgContent:(NSString *) msg]
}
```

and here is my c wrap code :

```
TextMessage* SendMessage(const char* contactNumber,const char* content){
    Messaging* msg = [[Messaging alloc] init];
    NSString* nr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:contactNumber];
    NSString* contentText = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:content];
    TextMessage* newText = [msg CsendText:nr CmsgContent:contentText];

    return newText;
}
```

you can see i return a textmessage, it is an event not a char,, how can i pass the event to unity,

my c# code is here:

```
#if UNITY_IPHONE
        [DllImport("__Internal")]
        private static extern string SendMessage (string contactNumber,string content);

#endif
    string phoneNumber="";
    string content="";
    void OnGUI () {
                phoneNumber = GUI.TextField ( new Rect (250, 125, 250, 25), phoneNumber, 40);
                content = GUI.TextField (new Rect (250, 157, 250, 25), content, 40);

        if (GUI.Button(new Rect (250, 250, 100, 30),"click me")) {
            SendMessage(phoneNumber,content);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's not the way it is working. You cannot just return something in C and expect it to appear in Unity / C#.
To achieve a "two way communication" you'll need to do the following.

---

### Unity => iOS

C# code

```
[DllImport ("__Internal")]
private static extern void _SomeCMethod(string parameter);
```

(Objective-) C code

```
void _SomeCMethod(const char *parameter) 
{
}
```

When you invoke `_SomeMethod` in C#, `_SomeMethod` in your (Objective-)  C code gets called.

### iOS => Unity

Objective-C code

```
- (void)callSomeCSharpMethod
    UnitySendMessage("GO", "SomeCSharpMethod", "parameter");
}
```

C# code (**`MonoBehaviour` script attached to `GO`**)

```
void SomeCSharpMethod(string parameter)
{
}
```

When you invoke `callSomeCSharpMethod` in Objective-C, `SomeCSharpMethod` in your C# code gets called.

---

### Converting strings

You'll have to convert your `NSString`s to c strings (`const char *`) and vice versa.

#### `const char *` => `NSString`

```
[NSString stringWithCString:string encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

#### `NSString` => `const char *`

```
[string cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

---

**Note:**
This is just a simple example on how to achieve a two way communication channel between C# and native iOS code.
Of course you don't want to hardcode e.g. the `GameObject`'s name in your code, so you can just pass that name (for callbacks from Objective-C) to your native iOS code at the very beginning.

Comment: Using Unity 5.3.5f1 here. I had to declare the Obj-C method as `extern "C" void _SomeCMethod(const char *parameter)` for the linker to find it.